# Automatically printing a pdf to a printer in real time

Tags: python

I have a pdf file with 10 pages.  I have to print each page to a default printer with respect to a real time output being received through serial communication. How to do this with python

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is incredibly broad.

Comment: One of the way is to use pySerial http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html

Comment: I am using arduino to count analog inputs and want to print each page when the count reaches a particular value and reset the counter. I am already using pyserial for communicating with arduino. So is there any way to  do this???